# Selenium WebDriver: Random Error determining if element is visible

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium 2.2.

I am trying to click on elements which are not displayed at first, but become visible
during the test. At first sometimes the webdriver seemed to work too fast so the Elements were not visible in time resulting in ElementNotVisibleExceptions. I added WebDriverWait to wait for these elements to become visible/clickable. But now I'm getting this random error when using

```
WebDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("id")));
```

same for

```
WebDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("id")));
```

here is the stacktrace

`org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error determining if element is displayed (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 219 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.20.0', revision: '16008', time: '2012-02-27 19:03:59'
System info: os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1 build 2600 Service Pack 3', java.version: '1.6.0'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:516)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:170)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:123)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:438)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.isDisplayed(RemoteWebElement.java:280)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.elementIfVisible(ExpectedConditions.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.access$1(ExpectedConditions.java:135)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$4.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:106)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$4.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$11.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:252)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$11.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:201)
    at MyTest.myTest(MyTest.java:xx)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:168)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:110)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:128)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:113)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:243)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:238)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:243)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:238)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:196)`

This only happens sometimes. Ignoring the WebDriverException might solve this problem, but that doesn't seem like a clean solution. It can't be a timeout issue because i tried setting my timeout limit to a minute and more and it still fails after a couple of milliseconds.

Anybody got a clean solution to that?

Thanks in advance

Edit: btw. I'm using the InternetExplorerDriver

Comment: 2.2 is positively ancient. What happens if you use the latest version? If that still fails, the next question will be, "Can you provide code, including the HTML page to test against, that will reproduce the issue?"

Comment: It still happens on the latest version. Unfortunately, I can not provide the actual code, but its basically just a richfaces rich:modalpanel which will be shown after a jsf a4j:commandbutton is clicked. after that i want to click another a4j:commandbutton on the rich:modalpanel. it fails, determining the visibility of the commandbutton on the modalpanel

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure page has only one modalPanel. Try get visible panel (java):

```
public WebElement getVisibleModalPanel(){
 for (WebElement element : driver.findElements(By.cssSelector('csslocator'))) {
  if (element.isDisplayed()) {
       return element;
  }
 }
 return null;
}
```

Implement wait for such thing:

```
(new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), timeout, 400)).ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class).until(
                new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {

                    @Override
                    public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
                        for (WebElement element : driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(locator))) {
                            if (element.isDisplayed()) {
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                        return false;
                    }

                });
```